# Given a right angled triangle ABC, where AP is the median and Q is a point on AB then find AQ in terms of given.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

> Problem: In a triangle $ABC$, right angled at $B$, $AP$ is the median. $Q$ is a point taken on side $AB$ such that $\angle ACQ =\alpha $ and $\angle APQ =\beta $ and let $CP = BP = x$, Find $AQ$ in terms of the given parameters.

What I have tried is draw perpendiculars from $Q$ on $AC$ and on $AP$ to get some trigonometry going but I am unable to proceed so I graphed it on the coordinate plane but I'm unable to proceed there too. So I looked at the options (its a multiple choice) and all of them seem to include $\cot \alpha$  and $\cot \beta$.

Rough Figure: 
[image: Rough Figure]

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone. Also, I am sorry to learn that I forgot to mention that I had assumed the distance $|AB|$ and it isn't given in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> Given $\angle QCA=\phi$, $\angle QPA=\psi$ and $x=|BP|=|CP|$,  find
>   $c=|AB|$ and $q=|AQ|$.

Let $|AC|=b,\ |AP|=u,\ |CQ|=v,\ |PQ|=w$.

\begin{align} 
b^2&=4\,x^2+c^2
,\quad
v^2=4\,x^2+(c-q)^2
,\\
u^2&=\phantom{4\,}x^2+c^2
,\quad
w^2=\phantom{4\,}x^2+(c-q)^2
,\\
b^2-u^2&=
v^2-w^2=3\,x^2
,\\
b^2-v^2&=u^2-w^2
=2\,c\,q-q^2
.
\end{align}

Considering squared areas of $\triangle CAQ$
$\triangle PAQ$, which share the same base $|AQ|=q$
and $h_{CAQ}=2h_{PAQ}$, we have

\begin{align} 
v^2\,b^2\,\sin^2\phi
&=
4\,u^2\,w^2\,\sin^2\psi
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\triangle CAQ:\quad
2\,x\,q&=
b\,v\,\sin\phi
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\triangle PAQ:\quad
\phantom{2\,}x\,q&=
u\,w\,\sin\psi
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
u\,w&=
b\,v\,\frac{\sin\phi}{2\,\sin\psi}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

By cosine rule

\begin{align} 
\triangle CAQ:\quad
q^2&=
b^2+v^2-2\,b\,v\,\cos\phi
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\triangle CAQ:\quad
q^2&=
u^2+w^2-2\,u\,w\,\cos\psi
\tag{6a}\label{6a}
\\
&=u^2+w^2-b\,v\,\sin\phi\,\cot\psi
\tag{6b}\label{6b}
,\\
b\,v&=
\frac{b^2+v^2-u^2-w^2}{2\,\cos\phi-\sin\phi\cot\psi}
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
b\,v&= \frac{6\,x^2}{2\,\cos\phi-\sin\phi\cot\psi}
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
u\,w&=
\frac{3\,x^2}{2\,\sin\psi\,\cot\phi-\cos\psi}
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}

From $\triangle PAQ$

\begin{align} 
2\,x\,q&=
b\,v\sin\phi
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
q&=\frac{b\,v\sin\phi}{2\,x}
=
\frac{3\,x\,\sin\phi}{2\,\cos\phi-\sin\phi\cot\psi}
=
\frac{3\,x}{2\,\cot\phi-\cot\psi}
\tag{11}\label{11}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
b^2+v^2&=
q^2+2\,b\,v\,\cos\phi
\tag{12}\label{12}
,\\
b^2+v^2&=
q^2
+\frac{12\,x^2}{2\cos\phi-\sin\phi\cot\psi}
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{align}

Substitution of \eqref{1} gives a quadratic equation in $c$:

\begin{align} 
c^2-q\,c+4\,x^2-\frac{6\,x^2\,\cos\phi}{2\,\cos\phi-\sin\phi\cot\psi}
&=0
\tag{14}\label{14}
,\\
c^2-q\,c+\tfrac23\,q\,x\,(\cot\phi-2\,\cot\psi)&=0
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{align}

with a suitable root

\begin{align} 
c&=\frac{q}{2}\,\left(1
+\sqrt{1-\frac{8\,x}{3\,q}\,(\cot\phi-2\,\cot\psi)}
\right)
\tag{16}\label{16}
,\\
c&=\frac x2\cdot\frac{3+\sqrt{9+8\,\cot\phi\cot\psi-16\,(\cot\phi-\cot\psi)^2}}
{2\,\cot\phi-\cot\psi}
\tag{17}\label{17}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

(1). In  triangle BQP, find $\angle BQP$ in terms of a, b and x

(2). In  triangle BOP, find $\angle BOP$ in terms of a and x

$\beta$ = (2) - (1)

Comment: You mean BAP instead of BOP?

Comment: but how does it include $\alpha$? (Since all the options seem to include $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both)

Comment: @ChiefVS I have shown you how to get $beta$. Can you try to find $alpha$ by yourself? If there are options, please list them for reference.

Comment: @ChiefVS For your 1st question, It is A. However, in co-ordinates geometry, we usually let the origin (0, 0) be O.

Comment: But it's way complicated as it is in terms of $cot^{-1}$

Comment: @ChiefVS The approach that I am using is simple enough. Maybe be you include the arguement of  $\cot^{-1}$ before we can determine which is simpler. It could be the case that both answers are equivalent to each other.

Comment: The image is misleading, 
the problem does not state that $|AB|$ is known,
the only given values are $x$
and two angles.

Comment: @g.kov Too bad to learn that the OP did not clearly state which are given and which are to be found.

Comment: I am sorry for that. @Mick I forgot to mention it clearly.  Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @ChiefVS No harm done.